# MPDF div not working inside table

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, mpdf

I am working on mpdf and it is a good library to convert html page to pdf, but when I put block element e.g `<div><p>` inside table cell it doesn't behave like a block element, it behaves like inline element.

code:

```
 <td><div>Block Element</div></td>
```

or

```
 <td><p>Block Element</p></td>
```

Is there a way to make it block element?

Or should I use other library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<td>` should be inside `<div>`

Comment: @PathikVejani Why? I'm having trouble using a <div> inside a <td> too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking for solutions to the same problem I just realized that according to the documentation, it's not a bug, it's a <strike>feature</strike> limitation:

> Block-level tags (DIV, P etc) are ignored inside tables, including any
>   CSS styles - inline CSS or stylesheet classes, id etc. To set text
>   characteristics within a table/cell, either define the CSS for the
>   table/cell, or use in-line tags e.g. `<SPAN style=”…“>`

Seems like there's currently no way around it. 
In my case I had to use `&nbsp;`s to indent (fake-center) a `<h4>` headline.

See https://mpdf.github.io/tables/tables.html

Comment: DIV's aren't working, but in some cases another table inside the 'td' element can help you out.

Comment: Not a 'feature'. A limitation.